# variable decleration inside if - why does it work in c++14?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, c++14

My compiler issues a warning when I declare a variable inside `if` - but it does compile, even though I use c++14 and not c++17 where this feature is officially introduced.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int foo(){
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    if (int x = foo(); x < 2){
        std::cout << "bla bla\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ ./bla.cpp --std=c++14 && ./a.out
```

Compiler:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

Warning:

```
bla.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bla.cpp:6:9: warning: init-statement in selection statements only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
    6 |     if (int x = foo(); x < 2){
      |
```

Does that make sense? Did g++9.4.0 implement a c++17 feature and allow me to use it for c++14 with just a warning?

If this is true, what's the harm of using this in my code? I'm guessing not all compilers will be so leniant, but once the code is compiled by a leniant compiler like mine, the binary will run as I expect, (making this a compilation portablility issue, but no run-time issues), right?

Comment: Sometimes what you use as a compiler might not be what you expect. For example on macOS the command `g++` (and `gcc`) is an *alias* for the default Clang compiler. Please don't use features that aren't fully supported for your target C++ version. And treat all warnings as *errors*.

Comment: A Warning is a Diagnostic which is all the standard says the compiler has to do. 3 compilers, 2 warnings and 1 error - live - https://godbolt.org/z/z9W6j41rv

Comment: GCC has the `-pedantic-errors` flag if you _don't_ want this lenient behavior and would rather like hard errors for (most) ill-formed programs, even if they are supported.

Comment: @user17732522 I actually do want this behavior - at least want to try to understand it better. I usually compile with `--Werror` so this wouldn't work on any production code I write, but I was curious to why this worked in the first place

Comment: If you are fine with using C++17 features, there is a switch for that too.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did g++9.4.0 implement a c++17 feature and allow me to use it for c++14 with just a warning?

Yes.

> what's the harm of using this in my code?

Because other compilers may disagree. The *same* compiler may disagree in newer versions.

Compilers tend to do things like this to make implementing the standard library easier. They may want to replace all of their `if` statements of the form `if((int x = foo()))` into `if(int x = foo(); x)`. They simply disable the warning inside of their headers.

But standard library implementations are written against a specific version of the compiler. So they use details of the compiler that others can't reliably use if they want to write portable code. If you're fine with relying on compiler-specific behavior, you can use these things.